# How to make Cardial Directions relative to the camera

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, movement

Lets suppose  tha my movement method my W goes towards north(just figuretvly) and my E goes towards east, If I rotate my camera to east I want my W to insted goes to north, goes towards east and my E to go towards south how do I do it?

Code:

```
public void OnMovement(InputAction.CallbackContext value)
{
    movement2D = value.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    movement2D.Normalize();
    direction = new Vector3(movement2D.x, 0, movement2D.y);
    direction.Normalize();

}

void ApplyMovement()
{
    isWalking = direction.x != 0 || direction.z != 0;

    float currentSpeed = speed * (isRunning && !isCrouching ? speedWhileRunningMultiplier : isCrouching ? speedWhileCrouchingMultiplier : 1);
    Vector3 currentDirection = playerCamera.DirectionToMoveByCamera(direction);
    controller.Move(currentDirection * currentSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    // ApplyAnimation();
}

void ApplyRotation()
{
    if (movement2D.sqrMagnitude == 0) return;

    if (playerCamera.PlayerShouldRotateByCameraAngle || playerCamera.isFirstPerson)
    {
        Debug.Log("sssssss");
        playerTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, playerCamera.cameraTransform.transform.eulerAngles.y, 0.0f);
    }
    else
    {
        float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(playerCamera.cameraTransform.transform.eulerAngles.x, playerCamera.cameraTransform.transform.eulerAngles.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        float angle = Mathf.LerpAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, smoothTime * Time.deltaTime);
        playerTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, angle, 0.0f);
    }
}
public Vector3 DirectionToMoveByCamera(Vector3 direction)
{
    if (PlayerShouldRotateByCameraAngle || isFirstPerson)
    {
        return Quaternion.AngleAxis(cameraTransform.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, Vector3.up) * direction;
    }

    return direction;
}
```

the method `DirectionToMoveByCamera` when I'm in first person my W goes towards where my camera is poiting  but If I like i'm in third person, my W A S D is not relative to where my camera is poiting(to the front of my player) note: `PlayerShouldRotateByCameraAngle` has nothing to do with it

Comment: This appears to be a repost of [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/205741/3d-first-person-rotate-character-unity) from yesterday

Comment: When you post a question, please take a few extra minutes to format your code (removing excessive empty lines and fixing indentation) so it's easier for us to read.

Comment: no it's a different question, the other question was about the act of rotating the character  which I could solve, this one is about the directions changing relative to the camera, like the directons are not relative to the front off my player when I rotate it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Camera-relative movement](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/125945/39518) / [Using Unity's transform.translate() to translate relative to an object](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/111313/39518)

Comment: I don't think it's the same issue (at least in interpreted this way)